# VSCode won't open console in an external window

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, console

I am a beginner in C# just recently learning it soon. Whenever I run my Project.cs file, it does not open in an external terminal despite the launch.json file has been adapted. My code is below:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/My Awesome Program.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Change the below line**

From

**"console": "internalConsole",**

To

**"console": "externalTerminal",**